# Couldn't find '.momd' file

Tags: ios, core-data

My app uses `CoreData`, with a model named : `mupo-ios.xcdatamodel`. This model is the second version of the original Model : Model.xcdatamodeld. I was using the `managedObjectContext` through a document:

```
        NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDocument"];

        self.document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

        // Set our document up for automatic migrations
        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];            
        self.document.persistentStoreOptions = options;
    }
```

And later, I access the `managedObjectContext` :

```
    self.managedObjectContext = self.document.managedObjectContext;
```

Now, I want to access to the main context directly, here's the code:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)mainContext {
    if (!_mainContext) {
        _mainContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        _mainContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }
    return _mainContext;
}
```

The problem is when I try to specify the `managedObjectModel` :

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (!_managedObjectModel) {
NSString *localModelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mupo-ios" ofType:@"momd"];
        NSURL *modelUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:localModelPath];    
        _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelUrl];
    }
    return _managedObjectModel;
}
```

The momd's file can't be found so the `managedObjectModel` can't be initialized. Can anybody helps me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem this way (I don't fully understand why it's working though) :

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
   if (!_managedObjectModel) {
     _managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
   }
   return _managedObjectModel;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This problem happened to me in a complex scenario. I had two xcodeproj in a single workspace.

I tried to use the same xcdatamodeld file in the second project **by dragging it from the first project to the second inside xcode**. This created a reference correctly, but even when adding the file to the "compile resource", the modm file wasn't created.

The solution was to **drag n drop the xcdatamodeld into the second project from the Finder directly** and not from the first proj in xcode.

Comment: Delete your xcdatamodeld file from your workspace before drag and drop from finder

Comment: It is true! Even in 2016, Xcode 8, this bug is still there.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me too. You can get a similar effect by adding the xcmodeld file to Build Phases -> Compile Sources - click + then Add Other... . Note this adds the xcmodeld file to the project sources again, so you may have remove the reference to avoid duplicate references.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
NSString *localModelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mupo-ios" ofType:@"momd"];
```

Change `momd` to `mom`

Comment: Is this model in a static library you made? Or is it all inclusive in one project? In targets->build phases-> copy bundle resources: Do you see your model there?

Comment: It's all inclusive in my project. I can see it in targets->build phases-> copy bundle resources.